# Get all pages to display at once

Tags: pages, loop, query

I'm doing a theme that is supposed to be ease to create, but I have now reached a standstill and need to get past this.

Is there a way to display/show all pages at once? Or can I create a custom query to display all the pages with templates and not only the content?

### Something like this:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
```

Number represents the page which is shown in fullscreen mode and when the pagelink is clicked we slide to the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=page' );
```

as seen at codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters

Comment: That just returns the content, not the actual page

Comment: so you want pull entire page from header to footer?

Comment: If that is the way to do it, then yes. But the header is already included